# Idiom for describing when you feel heavy and uncomfortable

Tags: meaning, phrase-request, idioms

I am asking for an idiom to describe follow feeling (It is called '찌뿌둥하다' in Korean):

'When we feel a little heavy and uncomfortable because of body aches and colds'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common phrase in idiomatic BrE is

> Under the weather

There are several examples of its use [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/under-the-weather).
.